# Индекс MySQL и битовые операции

Tags: битовые-операции, mysql

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос. Есть у меня в таблице размером около 15 000 записей поле mask, по которому всегда будет осуществляться выборка. Это поле является индексом тип tinyint.

Насколько я понял, если при выборке использовать битовые операции типа

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE mask & 1`

то индекс не используется. А т.к. это каталог товаров, то обращаться к БД будут часто, поэтому критично время выполнения запроса.

Как можно заставить mysql использовать этот индекс?

Comment: where mask = ? чем не использование индекса ? хмм

Answer (score 2):

Два варианта, и оба не совсем то, что вы хотите, так как MySql на данный момент не умеет так индексировать.

1. Вместо tinyint создать 8 (или сколько там?) различных колонок. mask_1... etc. Сравнивать с ними. Можно это делать в отдельной таблице при добавлении записи в основную: разбивать маску на отдельные биты.
2. Заранее готовить массив для операции where mask in (...). 
   Как вариант, можно оптимизировать, создавая where in для второй половины и where NOT in для первой.

В общем, все это костыли. Придумайте, как совершить эту же операцию где-то еще.

Comment: Первый вариант не подойдёт, т.к. время от времени придётся создавать новые колонки. А вот на счёт второго варианта я думал, наверное, на нём и остановлюсь.  
Спасибо!

Comment: т.к время от времени придётся создавать новый колонки// Увы. Если вы используете tinyInt, то там только 8 бит. Значит только 8 колонок. :)

Comment: А если использовать mask % 2 = 1?

Comment: А что это за конструкция такая?

Comment: Она вернет число, если остаток от деления его на 2 равен 1.

Comment: Не подойдёт такой вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант использовать клонку типа [set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html). Запрос `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE mask & 1` по такому полю сможет использовать индекс.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.